# ServiceStack - Customize Generated OpenAPI JSON using OpenApiFeature

Tags: servicestack, openapi

Using the ServiceStack `OpenApiFeature`, the generated `operationId` in the openapi.json file follows this convention:

`[RequestName][route path slice without first path*][http verb][digit if required  for uniqueness]`

The *route path slice without first path** simply removes the first item in the path.  So if the route path is `blog/author/name`, the logic would grab `author/name`.

This is defined in the `OpenApiService::GetOperationName` [method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi/OpenApiService.cs).  In some cases, this logic creates sub-optimal operation naming in tools that rely on `openapi.json`.  As an example, if you have a service that exposes `GET` operations for a customer's details, customer summary, etc. and the details request is defined like this:

```
[Api("Get a customer's details.")]
[Route("/customer/details", "GET")]
public class GetCustomerDetailsRequest : IReturn<GetCustomerDetailsResponse>
{ ... }
```

The route will be something like this (which is good):
`/customer/details?customerId=2`

...but the generated OpenAPI `operationId` would be `GetCustomerDetailsRequestdetails_Get`, which isn't great.

Is there a way to customize the generated `operationId` using the `OpenApiFeature`?  If not, is there some other naming convention that will maintain the REST-esque route convention but provide a better OpenAPI `operationId`?

**EDIT:** Thanks to [mythz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz) for pointing out the `ApiDeclarationFilter`.  It allows you to complete customize the generated `openapi.json`.  This is how I'm changing the `operationId`:

```
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature
        {
            ApiDeclarationFilter = declaration =>
            {
                foreach (var p in declaration.Paths)
                {
                    foreach (var httpVerb in _httpVerbs) // _httpVerbs is just a list of http verbs
                    {
                        // retrieve the operation value using reflection and pattern matching.  This is to prevent having to use a switch statement to go through each http verb and check if it's been implemented
                        if (p.Value.GetType().GetProperty(httpVerb).GetValue(p.Value) is OpenApiOperation operation)
                        {
                            // Set the "OperationId" property using the convention [RequestClassName]_[Http Verb].  Note for simplicity here, I'm not checking for a unique operation Id.  You should do that to ensure open api compliance
                            ReflectionHelper.SetProperty($"{httpVerb}.OperationId", p.Value,
                                $"{operation.RequestType}_{httpVerb}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the [API metadata attributes](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#open-api-attributes), you can further customize what JSON is returned using the [filters available](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#operation-filters), e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature
{
    ApiDeclarationFilter = (openApiDoc) => ...,
    OperationFilter = (verb, operation) => ...,
    SchemaFilter = (schema) => ...,
    SchemaPropertyFilter = (openApiProperty) => ...,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `ApiDeclarationFilter`.  That's exactly what 
I needed to customized the generated `openapi.json` metadata